# How do we route Youtube through another server?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, routing

I know it can be done through a VPN but I'm trying to make it more dynamic. I have tried using a 'tcpforward' script which did what it stated and forwarded packets to/from the youtube server. But that didn't work out because YouTube and Google have the same IP Address so instead of opening Youtube it would open Google.com although I specified the address to point to as youtube.com

Is there any other way of achieving this? For example I would want my server to open Youtube whenever I put this into my browser:

```
http://MyServerIP:80
```

Is there any dynamic way of achieving this?

I am running Debian 6. The following configuration worked but instead opens up Google in the browser.

```
./tcpforward -k -l 0.0.0.0:80 -l youtube.com:80
```

Comment: You could do this with a proxy server, such as squid.  But what are you trying to achieve by this?  There may be better options if we could understand the context.

Comment: I cannot open YouTube through my home connection since it is blocked so I always have to use a VPN connection which works on computers/smartphones but not on older mobile phones.

Comment: So "MyServerIP" is external to your network and is able to get to YouTube?  What OS is it running?

Comment: I am running Debian 6. And yes, that is an external IP. The following configuration worked but instead opens up Google in the browser.

./tcpforward -k -l 0.0.0.0:80 -l youtube.com:80

Comment: For that to work, you would need to change your hosts file to have youtube.com point to your server IP, plus any assets that youtube needs, along with the dns names for those.  Very difficult.  I assume you can ssh to this box though?

Comment: Yes I have the full box root details. We are talking about hosts file of the server or the client with the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using dynamic port tunnelling with ssh to achieve what you want.

Connect to your server using

```
ssh -D8080 MyServerIP
```

This will create a local port 8080 that you can direct traffic down and it will travel to your server, and appear to come from it.

To use this, you'll need proxy settings set up in your browser.  Firefox has an extension called FoxyProxy which will let you direct specific URLs or patterns of urls to the proxy server.

The proxy server would be a SOCKS proxy with the address:

```
localhost:8080
```

So all you'd need to do is in the proxy settings say `*youtube.com/*` should be proxied by `localhost:8080`.

Comment: That's a good method but 'pptpd' proxy is more easier than this one and it works on most smartphones as well. But like I said, I need a more dynamic method than this. Maybe the Squid proxy like you said if it helps me achieve what I need.